# Merge two arrays matching an id

Tags: javascript, angularjs, underscore.js

I have two arrays like

```
var members = [{docId: "1234", userId: 222}, {docId: "1235", userId: 333}];
var memberInfo = [{id: 222, name: "test1"}, {id: 333, name: "test2"}];
```

I need to merge this to a single array programatically matching the user ids

The final array should be like

```
var finalArray = [{docId: "1234", userId: 222, name: "test1"}, {docId: "1235", userId: 333, name: "test2"}]
```

Is there a cleaner way to do this, I have underscore library in my app, but I couldn't find a clean method to achieve this

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A solution using underscore:

```
var finalArray = _.map(members, function(member){
    return _.extend(member, _.omit(_.findWhere(memberInfo, {id: member.userId}), 'id'));
});
```

1. [**_.map**](http://underscorejs.org/#map) across the members
2. find the matching member info using [**_.findWhere**](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere)
3. [**_.omit**](http://underscorejs.org/#omit) the id key from the matching member info
4. [**_.extend**](http://underscorejs.org/#extend) the member with the member info

Comment: Great example how to do it... I was searching for something like this... Tried so many different ways with underscore.... But this was exactly what I needed. Thanks Bunny :)

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve using `foreach function` and creating the third array and displaying it.

```
$scope.members = [{docId: "1234", userId: 222}, {docId: "1235", userId: 333}];
$scope.memberInfo = [{id: 222, name: "test1"}, {id: 333, name: "test2"}];
$scope.finalArray = [];

angular.forEach($scope.members, function(member) {
    angular.forEach($scope.memberInfo, function(memberInfo) {
      if(member.userId ==memberInfo.id) {
          var test = {
            docId : member.docId,
            userId: member.userId,
            name: memberInfo.name
          }
          $scope.finalArray.push(test);
      }
  });
});
```

Here is the working plunker:

http://embed.plnkr.co/QRB5v2cI6SZOdZgdqDVR/preview

Hope it helps!

Comment: Post code in your answer...not just a link to another site

Comment: I tried a lot of different ways to merge two arrays with matching ids and this solution nailed it! I even tried using angular.merge() which was good but the ids did not match when the objects merged. So this nested angular.forEach example was just what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

```
function computeMembers(members, memberInfo) {
  return members.map(function(member) {
    member.name = memberInfo[getMemberById(member.userId, memberInfo)].name
    return member
  })

  function getMemberById(id, elements) {
    var index = elements.filter(function(element) {
      return element.id === id
    })[0]
    return elements.indexOf(index)
  }
}

console.log(computeMembers(members, memberInfo))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var members = [{
    docId: "1234",
    userId: 222
}, {
    docId: "1235",
    userId: 333
}];
var memberInfo = [{
    id: 222,
    name: "test1"
}, {
    id: 333,
    name: "test2"
}];
var finalArray = [];

_.each(memberInfo, function (item) {
    finalArray.push(_.each(_.where(members, {
        userId: item.id
    }),

    function (element) {
        element.name = item.name
    }));
});

console.log(finalArray);
```

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/q8L6n504/9/)

Answer (score 0):

On ES6 you can use .find and Object.assign() in vanilla javascript, no need of extra libraries.

```
let finalArray = [];
memberInfo.forEach(member => {
finalArray.push( Object.assign( {}, member, 
         { docId: members.find(m => m.userId === member.id).docId } 
    ))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a nested map and update the top level element with the additional field `date` where fields in the arrays match.

```
member.map(mem => {
    return memberInfo.map(info => {
        if (info.id === mem.userId) {
            mem.date = info.date;
            return mem;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please explain how this solves the original question as it does not seem to do that

Comment: I made a correction though, however what I did here was check where the fields matches which is the memberInfo id and the members userid, and add the additional field to the first array. The first array then contains and update of each item with the info in the second array.

Comment: Thanks for update. But please use the `edit` button add any explanation to your answer so people in the future don't need to read through all of the comments to find an explanation :-)