# filter records from arrays that do not match using angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs

```
var orders = [{orderId: "1234", user_id: 222}, {orderId: "1235", user_id: 333}, {orderId: "1236", user_id: 222}, {orderId: "1237", user_id: 333}, {orderId: "1238", user_id: 334}];
var users = [{user_id: 222, name: "test1"}, {user_id: 333, name: "test2"}, {user_id: 334, name: "test3"}, {user_id: 335, name: "test4"}, {user_id: 336, name: "test5"}];


var expectResponse = [{user_id: "335", name: "test4"}, {user_id: 336, name: "test5"}]
```

return users that does not match with orders using angular.forloop tried but does not work please guide how to fix it

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Merge two arrays matching an id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286520/merge-two-arrays-matching-an-id)

Comment: Yes agree but does not seems to work had copied from there

Comment: Because if have duplicate data in member also need distinct data

Comment: @Alax you are not supposed to _just_ copy, you need to make it work with your code, so adjust it appropriately

Comment: Okay my question is different i've two duplicate data in members do not wish to see filtered duplicated data here

Comment: @Alax `_` is from [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) library. It has pre-defined methods that you can use

Comment: question updated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use library like lodash.js

there you can use differenceBy() method

put your json array

```
_.differenceBy(orders, users, "user_id");

_.differenceBy([{"orderId": "1234", "user_id": 222}, {"orderId": "1235", "user_id": 333}], [{"user_id": 222, "name": "test1"}, {"user_id": 33, "name": "test2"}], "user_id");
```

check this url https://lodash.com/docs#differenceBy

remember before using lodas library you need to use lodash library.

Comment: hmm i like it but there is a problem i have string value in user_id key of orders variable but in users variable i have string and it is not matching what is the way to fix it any idea sangram

Comment: either you need to change the value as string or you need to change the value as integer useing parseInt() method

Comment: can we put array in comparator i.e _.differenceBy(orders, users, ["user_id"]);

i want to compare with type as well

_.differenceBy(orders, users, ["user_id", "type"]);

Comment: is this possible

Comment: check this example `_.differenceBy([{ 'x': 2, 'y' : 3 }, { 'x': 1, 'y' : 3 }], [{ 'x': 1, 'y' : 3 }], 'x');`. and also check lodash documentation. you need to pass a compair value to give instruction to the code that in which basis it will filter